Making an EXE file with PyInstaller, problem with astroalign module
I made a small program that read three fit files, align the files to eventually creating a gif file to view if any asteroid is present. The program works fine under PyCharm. The conversion to exe file using PyInstaller was also straightforward. However, when the executable file call the first alignment, an exception happen and make the program to exit.
Here the calling code for the astroalign module:
try:
    registered_image, footprint = aa.register(science_64f, reference, max_control_points=max_control_points_value,
                                              detection_sigma=detection_sigma_value, min_area=min_area_value)
except (Exception,):
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", "Something when wrong! Likely, list of matching triangles exhausted before an "
                                   "acceptable transformation was found.")
    sys.exit()

Not sure what to add that would help investigating this issue.
I download the latest astroalign 2.6.1 (still was made in 2016) and I'm using Python 3.11
I just installed the latest version of PyInstaller.
Dependencies (all met)
numpy 1.11 ; scipy => 0.15 ; scikit-image ; sep-pjw
Any help would be appreciated...
After removing tkinter messagebox, I was able to view the exact errors (below).


It’s a bit difficult to help you if you don’t provide the full error message and stack trace as part of your [mre].
